# How do I go about writing a program to send and receive sms using python?

Tags: python, sms, gsm, at-command

I have looked all over the net for a good library to use in sending and receiving sms's using python but all in vain!

Are there GSM libraries for python out there?

Comment: Need more details...
Send and receive SMS on a mobile, or on a computer connected to a Mobile by USB/Bluetooth?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [py-sms](http://code.google.com/p/py-sms/)?

Comment: The above link does not work. You can find the repo of py-sms here https://pypi.org/project/pySMS/

Answer (score 2):

[Python-binding](http://www.gammu.org/wiki/index.php?title=Gammu:Python-gammu) for [Gammu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gammu_(software)) perhaps?

BTW. It's GUI version ([Wammu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wammu)) is written in wxPython.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently written some code for interacting with Huawei 3G USB modems in python.

My initial prototype used pyserial directly, and then my production code used Twisted's Serial support so I can access the modem asynchronously.

I found that by accessing the modem programatically using the serial port I was able to access all the functionality required to send and receive SMS messages using Hayes AT commands and extensions to the AT command set.

This is the [one of the referneces](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/AT_Commands) I was able to find on the topic, it lists these commands:

```
AT+CMGL      List Messages
AT+CMGR     Read message
AT+CMGS     Send message
AT+CMGW     Write message to memory
```

They are complicated commands and take arguments and you have to parse the results yourself.

[There are more references](http://www.developershome.com/sms/cmgsCommand.asp) on the internet you can google for that reference these 4 commands that will let you work out how your modem works.

Answer (score 1):

I provided a detailed answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716946/how-do-i-enable-sms-notifications-in-my-web-app/1071496#1071496). I mention a Python interface to an SMS gateway provided by TextMagic.

Answer (score 0):

Also check [PyKannel](http://mobilehacking.org/index.php/PyKannel).

There's also a web service for sending and receiving SMS (non-free, of course), but I don't have URL at hand. :(

Answer (score 0):

I was at a hackday where we had free access to a few APIs, including [twillio](http://www.twilio.com/). It was very easy to use their python library to send and receive SMS, and we built an app around it in about 3 hours (twillio integration was about 15 minutes).