# Send AT-command through bluetooth from python application

Tags: python, sms, fedora, at-command

hai guyz,

how can i send AT-command through bluetooth from a python application?

OS:fedora 8

Any one please healp me with the code?

which package i need to import?

from where can i download it?

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161197/send-receive-sms-using-at-command-from-fedora-in-python-application.

Comment: this one specifically for bluetooth connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  this is better.......

```
import bluetooth 
sockfd = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM) 
sockfd.connect(('00:24:7E:9E:55:0D', 1)) # BT Address 
sockfd.send('ATZ\r') 
time.sleep(1) 
sockfd.send(chr(26)) 
sockfd.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a connection over bluetooth to your IP modem, you want to use the bluetooth
rfcomm driver:

```
michael@challenger:~> cat /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf  
rfcomm0 {
        # Automatically bind the device at startup
        bind yes;
        # Bluetooth address of the device
        device 00:1C:CC:XX:XX:XX;
        # RFCOMM channel for the connection
        channel 1;
        # Description of the connection
        comment "Blackberry";
}
```

This is the setup I use for mine - YMMV.

```
michael@challenger:~> cu -l /dev/rfcomm0
Connected.
ATI
Research in Motion BlackBerry IP Modem

OK
```

Once you have the rfcomm0 port, you treat the port as a standard serial port and you're good to go.