# Retrieve data from hardware(eg CCTV,RFID) if library/API is not available

Tags: python, c++, embedded, hardware, embedded-linux

I want to access data from devices like **RFID reader**,**CCTV camera** which will be connected to a device which has ***SUSE Linux*** in it.This is a proprietary device --> **Huawei AR515**.

But, I am not sure in what format, data will be produced by these devices. If i want to get data, say using `Python/C++` what will I have to do?

Help in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: too broad, you have to start with the devices and what interfaces they require, not all are expected to be the same so pick and choose.  If running on an operating system you have to deal with that and some may have drivers which implies an api so that would be your interface.  Otherwise you have to deal with the operating system to get at the hardware interfaces that these devices connect to.

Answer (score 1):

In python, maybe this way can helps you

[Reading serial data in realtime in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908167/reading-serial-data-in-realtime-in-python)

In C/C++ for linux platform, you can read directly in /dev/.
In both cases, is mandatory knows whats commands and sequences the device require. In general lines, if you before never try this and you're begginer, the first steps more appropriate are the AT commands.

This can help [How to Send/Receive SMS using AT commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161197/how-to-send-receive-sms-using-at-commands)

Comment: I connected Arduino Yun to my Ubuntu machine at port /dev/ttyACM0. I used pySerial librarary of python and was able to retrieve data ,but data was plain text. In above i am not sure about data format which RFID and CCTV devices will give.