# Huawei Cdma Modem, How can send sms via C# App OR AT command

Tags: sms, send, at-command, modem, cdma

I've huawei EC156  cdma modem, I tried to send SMS via AT commands with many commands, But always received response "command not support".

I have used the following commands:

**1- AT+CMGS**

**2- AT + GWWC**
Also, I didn't find any C# Libraries dealing with cdma modems.

Comment: I think that you have been downvoted (not by me) because of a poor research effort: in fact there are plenty of questions asking how to send an SMS through AT commands. Talking about your specific case: what commands did you _exactly_ send (please report the full command sequence)?

Comment: thanks for response, I tried to execute this command (AT+CMGS) in  huawei EC156 cdma modem, But the response is "command not support". i need any one helpe my to fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to check the AT commands user manual of your device and check their syntax.

`AT+CMGS` has two different modes:

- in PDU mode its syntax is `AT+CMGS=<PDU>`
- in text mode it is `AT+CMGS=< dest phone number>`

In both cases  `AT+CMGS` is wrong, and **`operation not supported`** is the error you get for a wrong syntax (after setting *verbose error* mode with `AT+CMEE=2`).

---

There are plenty of questions showing the correct AT commands sequence required to send an SMS, for example  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2161197/11336762).

I summarize that sequence here briefly:

Some things ti check before starting:

1. Make sure that the SIM is inserted
2. Make sure that the PIN code has been correctly inserted (by issuing `AT+CPIN?` you have to receive the `READY` response)
3. Make sure that the device is correctly registered to the network (by issuing `AT+CREG?` you have to receive the `+CREG: 0,1` response)

Then:

1. Switch to *text mode* by issuing `AT+CMGF=1`
2. Tell to the device the phone number you want send the SMS  to, by issuing `AT+CMGS=<PHONE NUMBER>`. The device will output the `>` prompt character
3. Write your text
4. Close the SMS by providing the **Ctrl-Z** character (`0x1A` ASCII code)
5. On success, the response `+CMGS: <N>` will be displayed, with `N` in the range 0-255 meaning the progressive ID of sent messages

Comment: I implemented checking steps . (AT+CPIN?) i received Ready. But ( AT+CREG?) received Error / command not support.

Comment: Is there another way te registered device to the network

Comment: Try also `at+cgreg?` and `at+cereg?`. Probably your module doesn't have the fallback to 2g  I admittedly didn't check it)

Comment: Thanks for your interactive, I also received error (command not support). My modem model is `Huawei EC156`. CDMA network

Comment: There must be a cdma specific command that I currently don't remember. Nevermind: make sure that the antenna is connected and wait 10-15 seconds. Then you will be probably able to send your sms.

Comment: Ps: according ti all the AT guides I checked `at+creg?` should definitely be defined.

Comment: I tried again same error. Also, I would like to inform you that I can send SMS from Huawei mobile partner. Is there a way to know how that app send OR import his libraries within my C# app.