# Sending SMS using Python

Tags: python, gsm, at-command

I am trying to send sms using python and a GSM modem connected to my local machine, I have successfully sent the SMS using AT commands but now I have a technical problem for which I need help, the server of my website is located in United States while I live in Australia, so if I want to use the SMS feature on actual site I have to fly all the way to USA and attach the modem to my server, I just want to know if there is a simple solution for my problem, something like passing request from server to my machine and send SMS from my local machine.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i go about writting a program to send and receive sms using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665536/how-do-i-go-about-writting-a-program-to-send-and-receive-sms-using-python)

Answer (score 2):

A practical solution would be to connect to SMS gateway service instead of implementing your own service. Nowadays they are really cheap or even free.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have purchased a special number for my SMS service, can I use that with SMS gateways?

Comment: I don't know, you have to ask them, probably some of them could let you set the CallerID to your callerid if they can verify you.